# Take snapshot of top

Tags: macos, top

I am trying to take a snapshot of top so that I can save it to a file. For example `top -n 10 > top.txt`. However top will of course continue to run, and I just want a snapshot. All the examples I can find for taking snapshots use the flag `-b`, but this doesn't seem to be supported on my version of top as I get `invalid option or syntax: -b`. I'm using MacOS big sur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top for MacOS supports [reduced options](https://ss64.com/osx/top.html) compared to the [standard Linux version](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html). This includes the absence of the `-b` option. However, there is logging mode, via the flag `-l`, using `top -l 1` should provide a non interactive single page snapshot.